# Two UIViews that share ALMOST the same UIViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a "Buy" page and a "Sell" page for products. They share the SAME UIViewController except for the fact that in one UIViewController it shows items for sale, and the other one for purchase. (Another difference is one button - it's has string A displayed in one and B in the other.

Can I make them share the same UIViewController with those changes, tho ? Can I define some arguments for each view ?

Comment: You could use a base `UIViewController` that had two trivially different subclasses. Put all of the logic in the base and just the differences in the subclasses...

Comment: Could you try to share some code sample to better explain your ideas?

Comment: I believe it is best practice to avoid subclassing, however I make an exception in the case of ViewControllers as their hierarchy is already massively subclassed. Would do what @Grimxn suggests

Answer (score 2):

You could use a base UIViewController that had two trivially different subclasses. Put all of the logic in the base and just the differences in the subclasses...

```
class BaseVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var items: [String] = []
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        // do stuff
    }
    // add all of your tableView or similar common stuff here...
}
class AVC: BaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.button.titleLabel?.text = "A"
        self.items = ["Sell1", "Sell2"]
    }
}
class BVC: BaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.button.titleLabel?.text = "B"
        self.items = ["Buy1", "Buy2"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a UICollectionView in my View. Does that mean I have to connect an outlet to it from two different views? Won't it make my app crash ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a BaseViewController and make it the parent class of your new view controllers

Something like below:

BaseController:
import UIKit

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController{

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Common initiation codes
}

// Write all the codes that can be shared between the controllers
}
```

Make separate classes for each of your view controllers and modify them as you require:

```
class SettingsController: BaseViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()//This calls everything you wrote as init code for BaseController

    //Write any view controller specific init code here
}

//If you have any other settings controller specific code, write here
}
```

Since I haven't seen your code, I can't say for sure if this is the right way. This method would still mean that you don't have to rewrite your code for each view controller classes and still keep it clean.
The above method is preferred when you are doing your layout and views by code.

If you are using a story board and depending on your specific need, I would suggest you do something like this instead:

```
//Initiate your controller like this from the previous controller
@IBAction func goToSettingsController(_ sender: Any) {
    let baseController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerID") as! BaseController
    baseController.id = "Settings"
    self.present(baseController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func goToAboutController(_ sender: Any) {
    let baseController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ControllerID") as! BaseController
    baseController.id = "About"
    self.present(baseController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And in your BaseController:
    class BaseController: UIViewController{

```
var id: String!
@IBOutlet weak var backGround: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customInit()
}

func customInit(){
    switch id{
    case "Settings":
        self.backGround.backgroundColor = .purple //Any controller specific code
        break
    case "About":
        self.backGround.backgroundColor = .green //Any controller specific code
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

}

You won't need three separate classes as mentioned before, but you can use the BaseController class for both your ViewControllers.

Comment: I have a UICollectionView in my View. Does that mean I have to connect an outlet to it from two different views? Won't it make my app crash ?

Comment: I will also illustrate another method.

Answer (score 1):

Create a xib file,
Add a view in it,
Use that view in view controller with different functions on different buttons

Watch this video for help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvQxXoV527w&t=754s